# SwiftUI | Preview not updating on @Binding var value change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning **SwiftUI** and tried to make a simple todo list but I'm having issues understanding why `@Binding` property doesn't update my preview.

The code is the following.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TodoRow: View {
    @Binding var todo: Todo

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                todo.completed.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: todo.completed ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.plain)

            Text(todo.title)
                .strikethrough(todo.completed)
        }
    }
}

struct TodoRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TodoRow(todo: .constant(Todo.sampleData[0]))
    }
}
```

The preview doesn't update when I click the square button but the app works fine. Am I using it incorrectly?

EDIT:
Even without .constant(#), the preview doesn't work.

```
struct TodoRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State private static var todo = Todo.sampleData[0]

    static var previews: some View {
        TodoRow(todo: $todo)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because the `Binding` that you're passing is a constant. And as the name suggests, it is a constant.

Comment: I updated the preview to use a @State variable and it still doesn't work. Can you provide any solution?

Comment: Assuming `Todo.sampleData[0]` is just a `Todo` struct,
 all works well for me in my test with your `EDIT` code. The preview is updated when I click the square button.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I'm using xCode Version 14.2 (14C18) and my preview doesn't update. I found an alternative solution that's also given by Apple in a WWDC 2020 video!

Comment: good idea to learn `@Binding` first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution in the article [Testing SwiftUI Bindings in Xcode Previews](https://www.swiftjectivec.com/testing-swiftui-bindings-in-xcode-previews/).

In order for previews to change you must create a container view that holds state and wraps the view you're working on.

In my case what I've ended up doing was changing my preview to the following.

```
struct TodoRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    // A View that simply wraps the real view we're working on
    // Its only purpose is to hold state
    struct TodoRowContainer: View {
        @State private var todo = Todo.sampleData[0]

        var body: some View {
            TodoRow(todo: $todo)
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            TodoRow(todo: .constant(Todo.sampleData[0]))
                .previewDisplayName("Immutable Row")

            TodoRowContainer()
                .previewDisplayName("Mutable Row")
        }
    }
}
```